# Understanding redux and saga in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample) and I am getting very confused with redux, saga...  In the [settings container](https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample/blob/master/MultiLangSampleApp/App/Containers/SettingsContainer.js) in the tutorial they use the following code to change the language of the app. I got very confused, I never used redux before and I am not sure that I completely understood the following code. I commented the code with what I was able to understood. Can you tell me if this right and help me to understand it better?

```
 // map the store state to the component props, this will make to current laguage value availble in this.props.language? But why do they need to do this step? this.props.language is never called
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    language: state.settings.language,
  }
}

// create a saga called changeLanguage and once called will execute SettingsActions.changeLanguage asynchronously ?

const mapStateToDispatch = dispatch => ({
  changeLanguage: (newLang) => dispatch(SettingsActions.changeLanguage(newLang))
})

connect the saga to the store
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch)(SettingsContainer)

// ??
SettingsContainer.propTypes = {
  changeLanguage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  language: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding mapStateToProps method will be used to receive redux state variables as props in your component from reducer and mapStateToDispatcher is used to pass the value to redux state variables through action.js and then it will be transferred to reducer.js it is like a cycle. Redux store stores all state variables in one place called One Store concept
For more understanding please refer this youtube video for Redux. I hope you will understand better and your doubts will be clarified. To understand Redux you should have basic knowledge on React JS then it will be easy for you to understand Redux flow.

React JS / Redux Tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBbSLZjvleMwldX8jGgXV6a